# using a column alias in sqlite3 where clause

Tags: sqlite, alias, sql

I know that in oracle/mysql/sqlserver `select` statement you are not able to reference a column alias in the `where` clause because it is executed before the `select`, yet it works in sqlite3:

```
sqlite> create table t (c1 text, c2 text);
sqlite> insert into t values ("a1", "a2");
sqlite> insert into t values ("b1", "b2");
sqlite> select c1, c2 from t;
a1|a2
b1|b2
sqlite> select c1, c2 as alias_c2 from t where alias_c2='b2';
b1|b2
```

Why is this possible in sqlite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sqlite3 with `SQLITE_DEBUG` flag enabled:

```
sqlite> create table x (x1 integer);
sqlite> insert into x values (1);
sqlite> insert into x values (2);
sqlite> insert into x values (3);
sqlite> insert into x values (4);
sqlite> insert into x values (5);
sqlite> pragma vdbe_listing=1;
VDBE Program Listing:
   0 Expire           0    0    0      00 
   1 Halt             0    0    0      00 
sqlite> select x1*x1 as s from x where s>-10 and s>-9 and s>0 and s>-4 and s>2;
VDBE Program Listing:
   0 Trace            0    0    0      00 
   1 Integer        -10    1    0      00 
   2 Integer         -9    2    0      00 
   3 Integer          0    3    0      00 
   4 Integer         -4    4    0      00 
   5 Integer          2    5    0      00 
   6 Goto             0   26    0      00 
   7 OpenRead         0    3    0 1    00 x
   8 Rewind           0   24    0      00 
   9 Column           0    0    7      00 x.x1
  10 Multiply         7    7    6      00 
  11 Le               1   23    6      6A 
  12 Multiply         7    7    6      00 
  13 Le               2   23    6      6A 
  14 Multiply         7    7    6      00 
  15 Le               3   23    6      6A 
  16 Multiply         7    7    6      00 
  17 Le               4   23    6      6A 
  18 Multiply         7    7    6      00 
  19 Le               5   23    6      6A 
  20 Column           0    0    6      00 x.x1
  21 Multiply         6    6    9      00 
  22 ResultRow        9    1    0      00 
  23 Next             0    9    0      01 
  24 Close            0    0    0      00 
  25 Halt             0    0    0      00 
  26 Transaction      0    0    0      00 
  27 VerifyCookie     0    4    0      00 
  28 TableLock        0    3    0 x    00 
  29 Goto             0    7    0      00 
s   
----
4   
9   
16  
25  
sqlite>
```

As can be seen from the instruction stack above, the loop over the rows (lines 8-23) repeats the `Multiply` and `Le` commands for each expression in the `where` clause, for each row in the table.

So to answer my own question, sqlite engine is able to use the column aliases by substituting their definitions from the `select` at execution time of the `where`.

Answer (score 4):

So, from docs

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE
>   clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is
>   executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

but current `SQLite` allows it

> SQL standard, column aliases can be referenced in ORDER BY, GROUP BY
>   and HAVING clauses. As an extension, SQLite also allows them in WHERE
>   and JOIN ON clauses, but again, such usage is non-standard (though
>   very convenient at times). Neither the standard nor SQLite
>   implementation allow referencing aliases in the SELECT clause.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate, because this functionality is not provided as an external extension.

Comment: I think that means an extension of the standard, not an extension of SQLite.

Comment: For completeness: the first bit (docs) is from the MySQL 5.1 documentation until december 2019 (https://web.archive.org/web/20091215124608/http://dev.mysql.com:80/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-alias.html). After that "doesn't allow" got replaced to the current "disallow" (https://web.archive.org/web/20221201092846/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html). The second (SQLite allows it) bit is from the SQLite mailing list in november 2011 (https://web.archive.org/web/20221201082738/https://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@mailinglists.sqlite.org/msg65230.html)