# SQLite: distinguish between table and column alias

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can SQLite distinguish between a column from some aliased table, e.g. `table1.column` and a column that is aliased with the same name, i.e. `column`, in the `SELECT` statement?

This is relevant because I need to refer to the column that I construct in the `SELECT` statement later on in a `HAVING` clause, but must not confuse it with the column in aliased table. To my knowledge, I cannot alias the table to be constructed in my `SELECT` statement (without reverting to some nasty work-around like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) AS alias`) to ensure both are distinguishable.

Here's a stripped down version of the code I am concerned with:

```
SELECT 
    a.entity, 
    b.DATE, 
    TOTAL(a.dollar_amount*b.ret_usd)/TOTAL(a.dollar_amount) AS ret_usd
FROM holdings a 
LEFT JOIN returns b 
    ON a.stock = b.stock AND
    a.DATE = b.DATE
GROUP BY 
    a.entity, 
    b.DATE 
HAVING 
    ret_usd NOT NULL
```

Essentially, I want to get rid of groups for which I cannot find any returns and thus would show up with `NULL` values. I am not using an `INNER JOIN` because in my production code I merge multiple types of returns - for some of which I may have no data. I only want to drop those groups for which I have no returns for any of the return types.

To my understanding, the SQLite documentation does not address this issue.

Comment: You cannot use column aliases in `having` clause anyway - use entire expression (`HAVING TOTAL(a.dollar_amount*b.ret_usd) NOT NULL`).

Comment: If I put this the aggregation again into the `HAVING` clause, does it not get executed twice, which would be terrible for performance? Apart from this, MySQL [seems to allow it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/why-does-mysql-allow-having-to-use-select-aliases) and a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10923190/3484568) seems to suggest that this is the case for SQLite as well. However, I could not verify the quote from the documentation.

Comment: It should be excuted only once - SQL engine should understand that. (You can test that, yes?) Well, I didn't know about MySQL nonstandard ways :) I would then use different alias - but this doesn't answer your question of course.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN all the return tables, then add a WHERE something like

`COALESCE(b.ret_used, c.ret_used, d.ret_used....) is not NULL`

You might need a similar strategy to determine which `ret_used` in the TOTAL. FYI, `TOTAL` never returns NULL.